# How to multiply time in different denominations?

Tags: dimensional-analysis, discrete-time

I am writing some software that must do generalized time multiplication of various denominations. I can't wrap my head around how to generalize it.

[edit] The use case is this. You have a clock measuring time and you want to provide a mapping (ratio) to accelerate or decelerate the clock. For example, every seconds passed is equivalent to 1 days passed. Thus, $clocktime = xseconds * ndays$, with n days probably represented in seconds.

For example, lets say I have :

$1min * 2min = 2min\\
60s * 120s = 7200s^2\\
7200s^2 / 60s = 120s = 2min$

Now, if I multiply time in days, for example :

$1days * 2days = 2days$

And in seconds :

$1 day = 86'400s\\
86'400s * 172'800s = 14'929'920'000s^2\\
14'929'920'000s^2 / 60s = 248'832'000s$

But, that is incorrect.

$248'832'000s / 60 = 4'147'200min\\
4'147'200min / 60 = 69'120h\\
69'120h / 24 = 2'880days$

So my question is, how do you generalize time multiplication from/to various denominations? Ultimately, what am I missing here? Ty

Comment: It's really unclear in what context you mean this here. For example in your first step, you ignore the units, multiply the quantities, and then add the unit back in. In the second step, you treat the two terms of the multiplication as quantities with units and you end up with a unit squared quantity. I could see why you might want to do either of those things, but I think you need to be internally consistent about how you define the multiplication of quantities with units.

Comment: @NoahSolomon Yes, I'll be honest, it is unclear to me as well. I will add an explanation of the scenario I have. Basically, computing time faster using a ratio. For example, define a timer where 1 seconds == 1 days.

Answer (score 1):

This is a programming question, but ultimately you must encode the unit as well as its value. That way multiplying $ms\cdot ns = (m \cdot n) s$, and then handle conversions between units using a conversion function (with whatever templating mechanism you have in your language). For good examples see the time libraries in C++ and Rust (C++ is chrono and Rust is Duration I think)

Comment: "and then handle conversions between units using a conversion function", How does one do that with the provided example of days multiplied in seconds? As you can see, simple conversions are incorrect, so my math is wrong...

Comment: $10d$ multiplied by $2s$ is $20ds$

Answer (score 0):

OK so here is what I believe to be the answer and the problem with the question assumptions.

When representing days as seconds, the units were wrong.

$1day \neq 86400s\\
1day = 24h * 60m *60s = 86400hms$

And so, when multiplying $1day * 2days$ represented as "seconds", the correct equation is :

$86400hms * 172800hms = 14929920000h^2m^2s^2$

To convert back to days and get the correct result :

$14929920000h^2m^2s^2 / 24h / 60m / 60s = 172800hms\\
172800hms / 24h / 60m / 60s = 2days$